# Redis organize dynamic keys and delete them at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, redis

I have search page in which I show results. 
I configured redis and able to do redis fragment caching for result set and it is working as expected.

For my application depending on user preferences, some elements in search results will be changed for individual users. So, what I need now is to cache for individual user.
I'm able do this part as well with below statement.

```
$redis.set("result_#{current_user.id if current_user}")
```

- My question is how can I delete all this cache for every user,
  because I won't be knowing for which user cache is created and also I
  don't to perform sql query on `User` to get all those `ID's`.
- Does redis-namespace help me in this and how can I delete a namespace and keys under it.
- And also is this best practice to have caching for user specific
- Does redis clears on each deployment. I mean when does redis cache get clears.

Comment: Are you using Redis only as a cache? If that's the case, you may want to configure it to free the memory by removing the least recently used keys. If you like the idea, I can tell you more about it. Other options involve keeping track of the keys you create. Using redis-namespace won't help you with that.

Comment: @soveran I'm using redis for cache purpose only. I will appreciate if you could tell me about freeing up the memory by removing least used keys and also tracking keys. I love to hear anything about redis caching.

Comment: I just replied, and ping me if you need any help with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can let Redis remove keys with the LRU algorithm. Configure the memory limit with the `maxmemory` directive, and then set `maxmemory-policy` to the value `allkeys-lru`. You can find more information about how to use Redis as a cache at [redis.io/topics/lru-cache](http://redis.io/topics/lru-cache).